# How to set an image in a header that adjusts to the edges of the page?

Tags: graphics, header-footer, geometry

I'm struggling to add an image to the headers of an A4 paper document. Additionnally, my document is `twoside`. That's the way I'd like it to look :

[image]

Basically the logo with the name and the triangles are one single image, spanning the full width of an A4 page (I've taken it from a Word template), and adapted to displaying on odd pages. I designed a second image for even pages.

I tried to put them in a `fancyhdr` style, using the command `\fancyhead[\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{even.png}]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{odd.png}}`. **The thing is the image doesn't adjust to the exact edges of the page**. I've tried different solutions : using `\setlength` commands to modify the margins; using `\fancyheadoffset` command to change the width of the header; splitting the image into three smaller images (triangles, inverted triangles and logo) that I could send into the corners using `\fancyhead`'s R and L options  ... None of them would work. So I figured I needed your help.

**So is it even possible to set an image in the header of a document to give the output above ?**

Here's a MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, fancyhdr, lipsum}
\usepackage[top=2.0cm, bottom=2.5cm, inner=2.5cm, outer=2.5cm, marginparwidth=0pt]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% These lines are my attempts at changing the layout
%\setlength\hoffset{0pt}
%\setlength\oddsidemargin{1cm}
%\setlength\voffset{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{85.0pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-85.0pt}
%\setlength\headwidth{\paperwidth}
%\fancyheadoffset{150pt}
%---

\fancyhead[RE, LO]{\includegraphics{logo.png}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\includegraphics{even.png}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\includegraphics{odd.png}} %

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want this on *every* page of your document?

Comment: No, not chapter pages, and not the front page and table of contents page. But I use `\thispagestyle{empty}` and it isn't a problem. Why ?

Comment: Why don't you want to split it in two images since there's a lot of blank space between the two parts?

Comment: That's a solution I have tried using `fancyhdr` commands, but it won't adjust to the edges of the page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using [`scrlayer-scrpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage) instead `fancyhdr`. Then you can define two new layers: one for odd and one for even pages. These layers can be added to the pagestyle `scrheadings`. So the images will not be on `chapter` pages because they are using the page style `plain`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, top=5cm, marginparwidth=0pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{mwe}% dummy text and example images

\newsavebox\topodd
\newsavebox\topeven
\savebox\topodd{\includegraphics[height=85pt,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-A}}
\savebox\topeven{\includegraphics[height=85pt,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-B}}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% page number in footer
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  topmargin,
  oddpage,
  height=85pt,
  contents={\usebox\topodd}
]{top.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=top.odd,
  evenpage,
  contents={\usebox\topeven}
]{top.even}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{top.odd,top.even}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Note that I have enlarged the `top` margin to 5cm.

Comment: I'm having trouble using your solution. Basically I've taken exactly the code you have typed and replaced the dummy images by my image files, and I get `LaTeX error : file 'scrlayer-scrpage.sty' not found... ! Emergency stop... \clearpairofpagestyles ! ==> Fatal error occured, no output file produced!`. That is when my images are in the same folder as my project, but ideally I'd like to put them elsewhere and refer to them with an absolute path. When I try that I get `0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 Bad Boxes, 0 Pages` bug. I don't understand. Could you help ?

Comment: The package `scrlayer-scrpage` is part of the [KOMA-Script bundle](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) since December 2013 (KOMA-Script version 3.12). Current version on CTAN is 3.17a. So may be you have to update.

Comment: Okay, the thing was I hadn't downloaded the full KOMA-script bundle, but let miktex manage the download after it saw `\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}` (don't know if it is how that works). I downloaded the full bundle with the miktex package manager, and it know works smoothly. This is definitely what I was looking for, thank you !